# How to get double quotes around folder names with spaces

Tags: c#, .net, string, path

Here is my code

```
string path1 = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files";
string path2 = @"Microsoft Shared";
string path = Path.Combine(path1, path2);

Console.WriteLine(path);
```

The output provides me

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared

I would like to have any folder names with spaces in double quotes as follows

> C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Common Files"\"Microsoft Shared"

How can I get that?

Comment: Are you sure? Where is that useful?

Comment: i am creating a batch file which needs these paths

Comment: If you need it really, you can reaplace \ with "\"

Comment: You probably want `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared"` then, as in: start with a `"` and end with a `"` and I expect you know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be with LINQ.

You can split your folder path into an array listing all of the folder names, then manipulate each individual element using a `Select()`.

In your case you would want to:

1. Split the string into an array (using the '/' to separate elements)
2. Format the folder name as `"{folderName}"` if the folder name contains spaces
3. Rejoin the array as a single string, with the '/' for your delimiter

Here is what that would look like, please note I have used 2 `Select()`'s for clarity & to help identify the different steps. They can be a single statement.

```
        string path1 = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files";
        string path2 = @"Microsoft Shared";
        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(path1, path2);

        var folderNames = path.Split('\\');

        folderNames = folderNames.Select(fn => (fn.Contains(' ')) ? String.Format("\"{0}\"", fn) : fn)
                                 .ToArray();

        var fullPathWithQuotes = String.Join("\\", folderNames);
```

The output of the above process is:

> C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Common Files"\"Microsoft Shared"

Comment: why u added .Select(fn => fn.Replace(@"\", "")) ? It seems redundant, as array folderNames cannot have element that contains '\\' char (due to how Split works).

Comment: @Set That was an oversight on my part, thank you for catching it. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension method

```
public static class Ex
{
    public static string PathForBatchFile(this string input)
    {
        return input.Contains(" ") ? $"\"{input}\"" : input;
    }
}
```

use it like

```
var path = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared";
Console.WriteLine(path.PathForBatchFile());
```

It uses the [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) feature in C# 6.0. If you are not using C# 6.0 you can use this instead.

```
public static class Ex
{
    public static string PathForBatchFile(this string input)
    {
        return input.Contains(" ") ? string.Format("\"{0}\"", input) : input;
    }
}
```